# Cordova - Securing stored data on iOS without KeyChain

Tags: javascript, cordova, local-storage, cordova-plugins, ios11.2

I have a Cordova app on iOS that currently stores data using localStorage for offline use. This data can be viewed in plain text if the user has root access (either on a jailbroken phone or with sideloaded apps).

I would like to secure this data. Ideally I would just store this in KeyChain but it is disabled on the clients devices. I've thought about encrypting the data but it will be easy to reverse engineer any javascript implementation.

Any suggestions? Thanks.